# Cosmos DB json array that matchs all the words

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need a query that can get me the document from a list of words for example if I use

```
    select c from c join (SELECT distinct VALUE c.id FROM c JOIN word IN c.words WHERE  word in('word1',word2) and tag in('motorcycle')) ORDER BY c._ts desc
```

it will bring both documents, I want to retrieve only the first one cause it matches the two words and not only one.

Document 1

```
 "c": {
            "id": "d0f1723c-0a55-454a-9cf8-3884f2d8d61a",
            "words": [
                "word1",
                "word2",
                "word3",
             ]}
```

Document 2

```
 "c": {
            "id": "d0f1723c-0a55-454a-9cf8-3884f2d8d61a",
            "words": [
                "word1",
                "word4",
                "word5",
             ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cover this with two `ARRAY_CONTAINS` expressions in your `WHERE` clause (and no need for a `JOIN`):

```sql
SELECT c.id FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.words, 'word1')
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.words, 'word2')
```

This should return the id of your first document.

Comment: this worked, but is there any other way like to use an IN clause?

Comment: In your case, you're trying to include two specific gates (that is, two distinct matches). There is no "match all" version of `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` so I can't imagine how you'd do this differently within a single query. And you can examine the RU cost. When I ran this for test purposes for you, it was under 6 RU (true, I only had two documents, but the point is... it's not a very expensive query).