# Query Azure Cosmos for items that have all elements

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Let's say I have couple sample items in my DB that look like this:

Example 1:

```json
{
    'id': 'someid',
    'columns': ['apple', 'banana'],
    'filters': {'car': 'red', 'truck': 'blue'}
}
```

Example 2:

```json
{
    'id': 'someid',
    'columns': ['apple', 'banana', 'carrots'],
    'filters': {'truck': 'blue', 'car': 'red', 'boat':'green'}
}
```

Fast forward to the present, I have a new set of `columns` and of `filters` that might look like:

`newcolumns=['banana','apple']` and `newfilters={'truck':'blue', 'car':'red'}`

I want to do a query like

```sql
select *
from f
where f.columns=newcolumns and f.filters=newfilters
```

but I don't care about the order and they have to be a complete match.  Neither set can be a super or subset of the other.  So in this case my query should return example 1 but not example 2.

As a note, there are two parts to my question, the `columns` matching is answered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484405/cosmos-db-json-array-that-matchs-all-the-words) but the `filters` field isn't a list so the syntax isn't the same.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that works for the `columns` since that's a list but the `filters` aren't a list, they a dict (to use python parlance) so there's something more to the syntax that I need.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I just posted an answer that (I believe) covers all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really match by doing an equality-comparison on two arrays like you had:

```sql
where f.columns=newcolumns and f.filters=newfilters
```

Instead, use Cosmos DB's built-in `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`, combined with `ARRAY_LENGTH()`.

Since `columns` is a scalar array, it would look something like:

```sql
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.columns, "banana")
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.columns, "apple")
```

For `filters`, that isn't an array, so... first check to make sure the key is defined, then check if the value is correct:

```sql
WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.filters.truck) AND c.filters.truck="blue"
AND IS_DEFINED(c.filters.car) AND c.filters.car="red"
```

note: probably a good idea to turn your filters into subdocuments, since your current schema is an *anti-pattern* (using values as keys). Something like:

```sql
{
    "filters": [
       { "vehicleType": "truck", "color": "blue" },
       { "vehicleType": "car", "color": "red" }
}
```

at that point you can compare with `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` again. Something like:

```sql
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.filters, { "vehicleType": "truck", "color": "blue"}, true)
```

Comment: Changing the filters into subdocuments is a good idea.  I probably won't do it *but* now I'll feel bad about it.

Comment: What's the analog to ARRAY_LENGTH for dictionary?