# Cosmo DB Array contains BOTH values

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple JSON document DB in Cosmo where I want to extract all 'Drills' that have a target of value 1 AND value 2.

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "drill": {
        ...
        "targets": [
            "Static Strength",
            "Power"
        ],
        ...
    }
},
{
    "drill": {
        ...
        "targets": [
            "Power",
            "Coordination"
        ],
        ...
    }
},
{
    "drill": {
        ...
        "targets": [
            "Body Tension",
            "Static Strength",
            "Power"
        ],
        ...
    }
},...
```

In the example above, lets say I want to get all 'Drills' where the value of `Power` AND `Static Strength` are present in `Targets`. How would I do that?

If I use `ARRAY_CONTAINS(["Power","Static Strength"], t)` I get all places where EITHER of the values are present in the `Targets` array.

I realize this might be a simple ask but im really stumped on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query Azure Cosmos for items that have all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339495/query-azure-cosmos-for-items-that-have-all-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `AND` in your filter to add an expression for each value.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.drill.targets, 'Power') AND 
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.drill.targets, 'Static Strength')
```

Note that `ARRAY_CONTAINS` takes the array as first parameter and in the second parameter the value you want to have included inside the array.

Comment: If you read the deleted comment i just had something a little wrong in the writing . Thanks, i realized why this did not work in my previous tries is because i was doing a join to targets. Thank you!